# Clean Architecture, UseCases and Entities

Tags: android, architecture, clean-architecture

Okay, so I just started a new Android project and wanted to try implementing the Clean Architecture by Uncle Bob. I have a nice beginning using RxJava and stuff from GitHub samples & boilerplates and Fernando Cerjas' blog (like [this article](https://fernandocejas.com/2016/12/24/clean-architecture-dynamic-parameters-in-use-cases/)), but still have some questions on how to implement some UseCases.

---

## TL;DR

Should an Entity have fields that are another Entity (in my example, `User` having a `List<Messages>` field)?

Or should the Presenter combine UseCases to build a ViewModel mapped on multiple Entities (then how to you code the mapper?)?

Or should the Presenter have a ViewModel associated to each UseCase/Entity, and create some kind of "wait for all data to onNext" to call the view.show() for each ViewModel?

---

Basically, should UseCases only return Entities? Can an Entity be composed of other entities (as in a field of the class)? Are Entities only dumb datamodels POJOs? How to you represent 'join SQL' queries?

As an example, let's take a simple users/messages app.
I want to implement two views: `UserList` and `UserDetails`:

- `UserList` displays a list of `Users`
- `UserDetails` displays a user's information and its latest messages.

`UserList` is pretty straightforward, and I can see how to code the associated UseCase and layers (code below).

My problem is with the `UserDetails` screen.

How should I code my `GetUserInfoUseCase` if I want all the data to be passed at the view at the same time (like building a ViewModel composed of a User class, with a field List)? What should be the return value of the `GetUserInfoUseCase`?
Should I code a `Observable<User> GetUserInfoUseCase` and a `Observable<List<Message>> GetUserLatestMessages` and merge them somehow in my presenter? If yes, how can I manage this, as I don't have the Observables in my Presenter (I'm passing only an Observer as my UseCases parameters)?

#### User Entity

```
public abstract class User {
    public abstract long id();
    public abstract String name();
 ...
}
```

#### Message Entity

```
public abstract class Message {
    public abstract long id();
    public abstract long senderId();
    public abstract String text();
    public abstract long timstamp();
 ...
}
```

#### GetUsersUseCase

```
public class GetUsersUseCase extends UseCaseObservableWithParameter<Boolean, List<User>, UsersRepository> {

@Inject
public GetUsersUseCase(UsersRepository UsersRepository,
                              @Named("Thread") Scheduler threadScheduler,
                              @Named("PostExecution") Scheduler postExecutionScheduler) {
    super(usersRepository, threadScheduler, postExecutionScheduler);
}

@Override
protected Observable<List<User>> buildObservable(Boolean forceRefresh) {

    if(forceRefresh)
        repository.invalidateCache();

    return repository.getUsers();
}
}
```

#### UsersPresenter

```
public class UsersPresenter extends BasePresenter<UsersContract.View> implements UsersContract.Presenter {

    @Inject
    GetUsersUseCase mGetUsersUseCase;

    @Inject
    UserViewModelMapper mUserMapper;

    @Inject
    public UsersPresenter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void attachView(UsersContract.View mvpView) {
        super.attachView(mvpView);
    }

    @Override
    public void detachView() {
        super.detachView();

        mGetUsersUseCase.unsubscribe();
    }

    @Override
    public void fetchUsers(boolean forceRefresh) {
        getMvpView().showProgress();

        mGetUsersUseCase.execute(forceRefresh, new DisposableObserver<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(List<User> users) {
                getMvpView().hideProgress();
                getMvpView().showUsers(mUsersMapper.mapUsersToViewModels(users));
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                getMvpView().hideProgress();
                getMvpView().showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### UseCaseObservableWithParameter

```
public abstract class UseCaseObservableWithParameter<REQUEST_DATA, RESPONSE_DATA, REPOSITORY> extends UseCase<Observable, REQUEST_DATA, RESPONSE_DATA, REPOSITORY> {

    public UseCaseObservableWithParameter(REPOSITORY repository, Scheduler threadScheduler, Scheduler postExecutionScheduler) {
        super(repository, threadScheduler, postExecutionScheduler);
    }

    protected abstract Observable<RESPONSE_DATA> buildObservable(REQUEST_DATA requestData);

    public void execute(REQUEST_DATA requestData, DisposableObserver<RESPONSE_DATA> useCaseSubscriber) {
        this.disposable.add(
                this.buildObservable(requestData)
                        .subscribeOn(threadScheduler)
                        .observeOn(postExecutionScheduler)
                        .subscribeWith(useCaseSubscriber)
        );
    }
}
```

#### UseCase

```
public abstract class UseCase<OBSERVABLE, REQUEST_DATA, RESPONSE_DATA, REPOSITORY> {

    protected final REPOSITORY repository;

    protected final Scheduler threadScheduler;

    protected final Scheduler postExecutionScheduler;

    protected CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    public UseCase(REPOSITORY repository,
                   @Named("Thread") Scheduler threadScheduler,
                   @Named("PostExecution") Scheduler postExecutionScheduler) {
        Timber.d("UseCase CTOR");
        this.repository = repository;
        this.threadScheduler = threadScheduler;
        this.postExecutionScheduler = postExecutionScheduler;
    }

    protected abstract OBSERVABLE buildObservable(REQUEST_DATA requestData);

    public boolean isUnsubscribed() {
        return disposable.size() == 0;
    }

    public void unsubscribe() {
        if (!isUnsubscribed()) {
            disposable.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Quite a lot questions within a single question. let me try to consolidate what I think I understood are ur key questions

- Can Entities reference each other? the answer would be: YES. Also in 
  Clean Architecture u can create a domain model where entities are interconnected
- What should be returned from a UseCase? 
  Answer: UseCases define input DTOs (Data transfer objects) and output DTOs which are most convenient for the use case. in his book uncle bob writes that entities should not be passed to use cases or returned from use cases
- What is the role of the presenter then? Answer: ideally a presenter is converting data only. It converts data which is most convenient for one layer into data which is most convenient for the other layer.

hope this guidance helps u to answer ur detailed questions

More details and examples you can find in my recent posts: 
https://plainionist.github.io/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-UseCases/
and
https://plainionist.github.io/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Controller-Presenter/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding UseCases, almost every single example I found of Clean Architecture implementation return Entities, then the presenter maps the entity to a view model. Is that just to avoid another dto object between entities and the rest of the world?

Comment: Uncle Bob writes in his book in chapter "which data crosses the boundaries": "We don’t want to cheat and pass Entity objects or database rows." If the DTO returned by the usecase Interactor is very similar to an entities probably the use case has to less logic

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to push your "instrumental" aware code as far as possible (on the circle).

Use cases are very close to the model and contain a lot of business logic - you want this layer very clean to be able to do quick and easy unit tests. So, this layer shouldn't know anything about storage.

But the fun part is when Room enters the room :) Room makes it so easy to have model-like objects that you can use around and IMO it's a grey area should you use Room annotated classes for your model or not.

If you think about Room objects as Data Layer objects, then you should map them to your business objects before reaching use cases.
If you use Room as a built-in mapper of DAO to model objects, then IMO you can use them in your use cases, although clean purists probably would not agree on this.

My pragmatic advice would be - if your model has a complex structure built in from multiple entities then have a dedicated model class for it and map entities to it.
If you have something like an Address, IMO just go with the Room entity.