# RxJava combining observers (not Observables)

Tags: android, rx-java2, observers

I'm still new toRxJava and I am a bit confused on some code I have, where I don't have direct access to Observables, but pass an Observer as a parameter of some method to execute an Observable.

I would like to combine two Observers in some way but can't figure out how to do it with Observers.

Here I want to "combine" the mGetPotatoes and mGetBurger to show the potatoes and burger only when both do onNext (would be zip() for Observables I guess).

#### Show me some code

```
    mGetPotatoes.execute( new DisposableObserver<List<Potatoes>>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(List<Potatoes> potatoes) {
            getMvpView().showPotatoes(mPotatoesMapper.mapPotatoesToViewModels(potatoes));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            getMvpView().hideProgress();
            getMvpView().showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    });
    
    
    mGetBurger.execute( new DisposableObserver<Burger>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Burger burger) {
            getMvpView().showBurger(mBurgerMapper.mapBurgerToViewModel(burger));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            getMvpView().hideProgress();
            getMvpView().showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

### Edit

This question is a subset of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119036/clean-architecture-usecases-and-entities) where the template code for the mGetPotatoes and mGetBurger (that are UseCases) is.

Comment: you need to rethink your design to make the observables available.

Comment: That would be the easy solution, but I can't, it's part of a framework I don't have access to (Clean Architecture). I'm exploring different kind of possibilities, and this is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would sugegst you to change your architecture so the`Observable` is returned and you can *manipulate* it (change the scheduler, perform some actions, etc)

In case that option is not feasible you may get a workaround with [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)s. A `Subject` is an `Observer` which is also an `Observable`.

For your case:

1. Create a couple of `PublishSubject`
2. Combine both (with the `zip`) operator and subscribe to the result
3. Pass both subjects to your original use cases

Comment: I can't change the architecure, and the Observable is added to a compositeDisposable (I edited my subject to add a link to the code of the template for the Burgers and Potatoes). Could you provide pseudo-code regarding the Subject? I only want to"synchronize" the operations so that I can show burgers and potatoes at the same time, if possible.

Comment: I added the steps you have to make. Try to implement it by yourself with that help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what framework this is, but you can turn back the `execute` calls into `Observable`s by wrapping them:

```
Observable<List<Potatoes>> obs = new Observable<List<Potatoes>>() {
    @Override public void subscribeActual(final Observer<? super List<Potatoes>> s) {
        mGetPotatoes.execute(new DisposableObserver<List<Potatoes>>() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                s.onSubscribe(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<Potatoes> potatoes) {
                s.onNext(potatoes);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                s.onComplete();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                s.onError(e);
            }
        } 
    }
};
```